# Map Activity with GPS cause Crash in JellyBean Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have created an App and works fine on A real device with Gingerbread (I haven't any others devices at the moment).
The problem:

If I try to run the same App in the emulator configured to use JellyBean and Google Api when I open an activity that show a google map, Crashes without any error log,
simply the screen becomes black and Eclipse open a debug perspective that shows

*"Source Not Found"*

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2059    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2084 
    ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 130    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1195  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4745    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 786  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 553 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

... nothing about the missing source or the line in my class that has caused the error in logcat

Comment: Can you show the actual Logcat stacktrace of the exception? Just click the disconnect button and read your Logcat

Comment: The strange thing: The Logcat is totally clean, doesn't shows any error, these that I have written are the only info about the issue

Comment: You have to have the LogCat open, and when Eclipse tells you there has been an exception, you have to click the "disconnect" button to actually see the stack trace.

Comment: Yes, the logcat works and trace everything but nothing about this error... simply the screen became black and eclipse turn on debug perspective with the info that I have posted in the question when I open the activity with the map.

Comment: Dude, do you press disconnect or not? Because you have to press disconnect on Eclipse to actually see the stack trace of the exception

Comment: Disconnect? Where? I can see all the errors, status etc when the app crash... only in this case the error doesn't shows details in the stack trace.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18378/discussion-between-tolgap-and-asgard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen in these cases:

A) Your activity doesn't extends MapActivity(but if works on real device this is not the case)

B) Your app doesn't import Google Api (but if works on real device this is not the case)

C) The emulator is configured to use Android SDK instead Google API

D) There is some line that refers to null value in the emulator this could happen if you invoke `getLastKnownLocation(...)`: because your device has already known any location your app works on the smartphone but not in a new emulator

Do some test and let me know if the problem persists post the code of your Activity.